# Delphi XE2 Firemonkey - Add Image to TListBox (from file)

Tags: firemonkey

i create a simple application, 
for Delphi XE2 Firemonkey i have problem to load an image to TListBoxItem ! 
i tried , this steps :

**[1]:** http:/ /i.stack.imgur.com/b1w3d.png

**[2]:** http:/ /i.stack.imgur.com/GGyLT.png

**[3]:** http:/ /i.stack.imgur.com/1kYZn.png

**[4]:** http:/ /i.stack.imgur.com/7fuug.png

Code On Button Click :

```
var
 xItem : TListBoxItem;


begin
xItem := TListBoxItem.Create(nil);
xItem.Parent := ListBox1;
xItem.Height := 90; // just for test !

// code to load image file [edit1.Text] !!

xItem.Text := edit2.Text;

end;
```

Someone help me , to complete this simple !

///Thinks And sorry for my english !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Off the top of my head:

```
var Image: TImage;

...

Image := TImage.Create(xItem);
Image.Parent := xItem;
Image.Bitmap.LoadFromFile(<FileName>);


Image.Align := TAlignLayout.alClient;  //(Not strictly necessary but guarantees images will not be positioned out of view).
```

Comment: Solved ! (y) thinks ^^